# In how many ways can $10$ chocolates be distributed to $3$ people such that no one gets more than $4$?

Tags: combinatorics

$10$ chocolates are distributed to $3$ people such that no one gets more than $4$ or $A,B,C \leq 4$. How many ways can this be done?

I know how to do this if the condition is every person gets at least one. Here the condition is different. So need help.

Comment: $0$ chocolates?

Comment: Zero chocolates are distributed to three persons?  There is clearly only one way for that to occur, namely when everyone gets none.  If you had a number larger than $0$, then approach via inclusion-exclusion on whether or not the upper bound requirement for each of $A,B,C$ is violated.

Comment: Problem needs to be edited. There is only one way to distribute $0$ chocolates. ... Also, you need to explain what tools you have available. Inclusion/Exclusion? Generating functions? And what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry it is not 0 chocolates. It is 10 chocolates. My mistake in typing

Comment: The end result is the same as what I mentioned already.  Let $\chi_A$ denote the event that the upper bound condition is violated for person $A$, in other words $A>4$.  In other words $A\geq 5$.  You say you know how to do it if everyone gets at least one, you should then also know how to do it if a specific person gets at least five, or multiple people get at least five.

Comment: Apply inclusion-exclusion.  We try to find $|\chi_A^c\cap \chi_B^c\cap \chi_C^c| = |\Omega|-|\chi_A\cup \chi_B\cup \chi_C| = |\Omega| - |\chi_A|-|\chi_B|-|\chi_C|+|\chi_A\cap \chi_B|+|\chi_A\cap C|+|\chi_B\cap \chi_C|$ noting that in this case intersections of all three events is empty (since there are only ten chocolates, it is impossible for all three people to have at least five).

Answer (score 3):

Set:

- $A'=4-A$
- $B'=4-B$
- $C'=4-C$

Then $A',B',C'$ must be elements of $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ with: $$A'+B'+C'=2\tag1$$

If $A',B',C'$ are nonnegative integers satisfying this equation then automatically they will be elements of $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ , so we can restate the problem as: find nonnegative integers $A',B',C'$ that satisfy (1). For solving this [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) can be applied.

We find:  $$\binom{2+(3-1)}{3-1}=\binom42=6$$ possibilities.

Comment: Short and sweet ! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

drhab has provided you with an elegant solution to this problem based on the assumption that the chocolates are indistinguishable.  I will make the same assumption.

We wish to distribute ten chocolates to three people so that no person receives more than four chocolates.  The number of ways we can do this is equal to the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10 \tag{1}$$
in the non-negative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_1, x_2, x_3 \leq 4$.

The number of ways ten chocolates can be distributed to three people is the number of solutions of equation 1 in the non-negative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of ten ones.  For instance,
$$+ 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 6$, and $x_3 = 4$, while 
$$1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 5$, $x_2 = 3$, and $x_4 = 2$.  Thus, the number of solutions of equation 1 in the non-negative integers is the number of ways two addition signs can be inserted into a row of ten ones, which is 
$$\binom{10 + 2}{2} = \binom{12}{2}$$
since we must choose which two of the twelve symbols (ten ones and two addition signs) will be addition signs.

However, we have counted solutions in which at least one person receives more than four chocolates.  We must exclude those cases.

Notice that $2 \cdot 5 = 10$, so at most two of the people could receive more than four chocolates.

Suppose $x_1 > 4$.  Since $x_1$ is an integer, then $x_1 \geq 5$.  Let $y_1 = x_1 - 5$.  Then $y_1$ is a non-negative integer.  Substituting $y_1 + 5$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
y_1 + 5 + x_2 + x_3 & = 10\\
y_1 + x_2 + x_3 & = 5 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the non-negative integers with 
$$\binom{5 + 2}{2} = \binom{7}{2}$$
solutions.  There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to select a person to receive more than four chocolates.  Hence, the number of ways of distributing ten chocolates to three people so that one person receives more than four chocolates is 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{2}$$

However, if we subtract this number from the total number of ways of distributing ten chocolates, we will have subtracted those solutions in which two people received more than four chocolates twice.  Suppose $x_1, x_2 > 4$.  Let $y_1 = x_1 - 5$; let $y_2 = x_2 - 5$.  Then $y_1, y_2$ are non-negative integers.  Substituting $y_1 + 5$ for $x_1$ and $y_2 + 5$ for $x_2$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
y_1 + 5 + y_2 + 5 + x_3 & = 10\\
y_1 + y_2 + x_3 & = 0 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the non-negative integers with 
$$\binom{0 + 2}{2} = \binom{2}{2} = 1$$
solution (namely $y_1 = y_2 = x_3 = 0$).  Since there are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of selecting two people to receive five chocolates each, the number of ways two people could receive more than four chocolates is 
$$\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of ways ten chocolates can be distributed to three people so that no person receives more than chocolates is 
$$\binom{12}{2} - \binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{2} + \binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{2} = 6$$
As a check, they are $(2, 4, 4), (4, 2, 4), (4, 4, 2), (3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 3), (4, 3, 3)$.

Comment: I didn't understand the step after y1 + y2 + y3 = 0.Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: The only solution to equation $y_1 + y_2 + x_3 = 0$ is $y_1 = 0$, $y_2 = 0$, and $x_3 = 0$.  Remember that $y_1 = x_1 - 5$ and $y_2 = x_2 - 5$.  Thus, this solution is equivalent to the distribution $x_1 = 5$, $x_2 = 5$, and $x_3 = 0$.  However, we could also have $x_1 = 5$, $x_2 = 0$, and $x_3 = 5$, or $x_1 =  0$, $x_2 = 5$, and $x_3 = 5$.  That is, there are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of selecting two of the three people to receive five chocolates.  Thus, the number of ways two people could receive five chocolates apiece while the third person receives none is $\binom{3}{2}$.

Comment: Yes this point I understood, but why multiply with 3 c 2 by 2 c 2? This is where I got confused.

Comment: The term $\binom{2}{2} = 1$ represents the number of solutions of the equation $y_1 + y_2 + x_3 = 0$ in the non-negative integers.  It counts the number of ways to place two addition signs in a row of zero ones, which is $\binom{0 + 2}{2}$, since we must choose which two of the two symbols (zero ones and two addition signs) will be addition signs.  I just included the $\binom{2}{2}$ to be consistent with the two preceding cases.  I apologize for the confusion it caused.

Comment: Finally.  Sorry about that.